# How to add testCompile dependencies to IDE classpath

Tags: android, junit, gradle, gradle-android-test-plugi

I have been struggling with unit-test-android problem for quite a long time. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17845564/878514), [this](http://www.element84.com/easy-testing-with-android-studio.html) and [that](http://tryge.com/2013/02/28/android-gradle-build/), finally I found the [gradle-android-test-plugin](https://github.com/JakeWharton/gradle-android-test-plugin) and even got it working. I can now run the tests with `gradlew test` command.

But, writing those tests in IDE (Android Studio or IntelliJ 13) is far from comfortable, because it does not see the junit & Robolectric dependencies added with `testCompile` dependency.

Is there any way to add these dependencies to the IDE classpath but still avoid to package them in the production app (thus, AFAIU `compile` dependency cannot be used)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [testCompile results in Android studio not resolving dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908695/testcompile-results-in-android-studio-not-resolving-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with IntelliJ 14.1.3 today. The solution was to run the steps outlined [here](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/unit-testing-support). Basically:

1. Add JUnit and other dependencies via `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.+'`, etz
2. Put test sources in `src/test/java/...`
3. **To make the IDE find the test-dependencies** (gradle will find them fine), open the "Build Variants"-view and set "Test Artifact" to "Unit Test". In "Project Structure", the testing dependencies should show up in your module with the "Test"-scope
4. The commandline to run a test is `testXxx`, where `Xxx` is the build-type (debug/release/etz).

The important step here is the one in the "Build Variants" view. After you change it to "Unit Test", it will index and your libraries and full auto-completion are available.

Answer (score 0):

For my Android test dependencies, I use instrumentTestCompile instead of testCompile. This works for me when running my tests in Android Studio. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `idea` plugin. That should set up test dependencies for you. You'll need to import the plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

Then run `gradle idea`, to generate module file (`*.iml`) and re-load your project. Note you'll have to be using non-directory based idea configuration for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA you need to configure couple things in your `build.gradle`

```
// add idea plugin
apply plugin: 'idea'
// make sure `configurations.testCompile` is added to idea.module
idea {
    module {
        scopes.TEST.plus += [ configurations.testCompile ]
    }
}
```

For more info see:
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html

Any dependency included with `testCompile` will be automatically imported into IDEA.